# Java library jvm.dll price

Tags: java

Is it legal to download jvm.dll file free? Does it have any price or its just free for all? I have not found information about price or any license just for this file.

Thanks.

Comment: Even though I don't know what file this actually is, I'd say it's not "legal". All proper software has a license with it. If you were not given a license (open source or commercial, does not matter) you can not know what the license is and you can therefore not use the software "legally".

Comment: This library is included in java programm default.  Could it be not legal this way?

Comment: This is a legal question and off topic for SO. But the jre is for free. You can download and install from oracle or openjdk ...

Comment: You can download and install the JRE for free, but you can't redistribute the jvm.dll by itself, not only is it not legal to copy it without the license, it wouldn't work.

Comment: What about case when this file was deleted? Why cant I download just this library and work on. Is it needed to reinstall all software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to [Oracle JRE redistribution terms](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html) for which files must be redistributed with the JRE if you are shipping it with your application.  So you can't just provide the jvm.dll file, but there is no cost for redistributing the JRE.

If you have questions more detailed questions about the redistribution terms, I would suggest you contact Oracle directly, not a web site.